# Batch script to read from file name from source file and write path of all occurrences into output file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I need a batch script that reads a value from a file and searches for it in a directory tree.
It should print paths and file name of all the occurrences into an output file.
The in put file will have multiple values.

```
    Directory structure  
    Dir1/DirA/file.txt  
    Dir1/DirA/file1.txt  
    Dir1/DirB/file.txt  
    Dir1/DirA/file2.txt  
    Dir1/DirC/file5.txt  
    Dir1/DirX/file5.txt  


    Source file  
    file.txt  
    file1.txt  
    file2.txt  
    file5.txt  
    file9.txt  

    Desired Output file  

    Dir1/DirA/file.txt  
    Dir1/DirB/file.txt  
    file.txt Count 2  

    Dir1/DirA/file1.txt  
    file1.txt Count 1  

    Dir1/DirA/file2.txt  
    file1.txt Count 1  

    Dir1/DirC/file5.txt  
    Dir1/DirX/file5.txt  
    file5.txt Count 2  

    file9.txt Count 0
```

Comment: The expectation is that you provide a script showing what you've done so far and where you are stuck with it.

Comment: **pleaz send teh codez"*

Answer (score -1):

There are two critical components in this solution: one get the path and the file name together, the second one to test if the file exist.

1. Use the modify to get path info
   http://technogadge.com/how-to-clear-vivaldi-browser-history-cache-cookies/
2. Use the exist keyword in if statement to detect if the file exist

   if exist filepath (

   echo "got it"

   )